# Cannot save DataFrame to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

For some reason the code does not give any error, but it does not save DataFrame to S3 bucket's folder. I have a feeling that the cause is `format("json").text("s3n...")`, however I also tried `save` and it did not work. How to debug it and see why the content is not saved in S3?

```
        val conf = new SparkConf()
          .setAppName("TEST-APP")
 .setMaster(ConfigFactory.load("app.conf").getConfig("conf").getString("spark.master"))

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
        sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", Utils.getAWS_ACCESS_KEY())
        sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", Utils.getAWS_SECRET_KEY())
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(refreshingIntervalSeconds.toInt))
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

        val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
        ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

        stream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>

          val df = rdd.toDF()
          val datehour = sdf.format(new Date(time.milliseconds))
          val finalDf = df.withColumn("datehr", lit(datehour))
          finalDf.write.mode("append").partitionBy("datehr").format("json").text("s3n://" + Utils.getAWS_BUCKET() + "/" + Utils.getAWS_FOLDER() + "/test.json")

        }
```

Comment: Is that all the code you have? The stream would not start until you call `ssc.start()`, which could explain why you don't see anything writing out to S3. Take a look at the example on the upstream guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: @MrChristine: No, I surely have `ssc.start()`. Here I putted only the parts of code related to the question.